# Add 2 models inside of a parent model

Tags: angular

I am trying to add 2 models into another parent model however when I console log the parent model I get a blank response. Please have a look at my code below.

*Child model 1*

```
export class CompanyMedicalAidProvider {

  corporateId: string;
  active: boolean = true;
  selectedMAP: Array<SelectedMap>;

}
```

*Child model 2*

```
export class CompanyGapCoverProvider {

  gapCoverProviders: Array<GapCoverProviders>;

}
```

*Parent model*

```
export class BenefitProvider {

  CompanyGapCoverProvider: Array<CompanyGapCoverProvider>;
  CompanyMedicalAidProvider: Array<CompanyMedicalAidProvider>;

}
```

*.ts file*

```
companyBenefitProvider: BenefitProvider;

constructor() {
 this.companyBenefitProvider = new BenefitProvider();
}

ngOnInit() {
 console.log(this.companyBenefitProvider);
}
```

The payload in the console log is blank like this

```
{}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: console.log writes out the javascript object. at the javascript level types don't exist. after instantiating your BenefitProvider, both those elements are undefined. you will have to assign values to them if you want to see them in the log output.

Comment: ok how would I reassign the child models into the parent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

either pass the values for those 2 arrays via the constructor and assign them there:

```
constructor( companyGapCoverProvider: Array<CompanyGapCoverProvider>,
  companyMedicalAidProvider: Array<CompanyMedicalAidProvider>) {
  this.CompanyGapCoverProvider = companyGapCoverProvider;
  this.CompanyMedicalAidProvider = companyMedicalAidProvider;
}
```

or just construct an object that looks like the type you defined.

for example

```
constructor() {
 this.companyBenefitProvider = {
   CompanyGapCoverProvider: [],
   CompanyMedicalAidProvider: []
 };
}
```

typescript uses a concept called "structural typing".

for further details i suggest you read up on typescript basics: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html